# Error in using Swift framework(SDK) in react native (Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65.)

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, sdk, frameworks

I'm trying to use TMap(one of the map of Korea) in react-native.
TMap proivdes Swift Framework(SDK) for IOS.

I could not launch ios simulator with 'react-native run-ios'. there was warning and error.

(node:13189) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening TMapAppTest.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

When I tried to build in Xcode, there was issue for 'Target Integiry' - 'Building for IOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'TMapSDK.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator.

Here is detail of what I've done.
I added TMapSDK.framework at 'Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded content' after opening './ios/MyProjectName.xcodeproj'
and then just do 'react-native run-ios'.

I could success to launch with XCode after add 'TMapSDK.framework' but it failed with react-native.